# AWS ssh error " aws i/o error - read failed : unknown error "

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, redhat

i am not able to connect my aws ec2 server. The server showing me error are as below. 
server information as below

Server type : t1.micro

OS : RHEL-6.5_GA-20140929-x86_64-11-Hourly2-GP2

security rule : port 22 allow for all (it's for testing)

error outputs are below.

```
[root@ip-172-31-18-188 SRV-admin]# ssh -i web-srv-key.pem ec2-user@xx.xx.xxx.xx
The authenticity of host 'xx.xx.xxx.xx (xx.xx.xxx.xx)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 02:0c:d4:e6:1b:d3:54:2e:05:33:25:a2:99:c1:1e:9a.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'xx.xx.xxx.xx' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Connection closed by xx.xx.xxx.xx
[root@ip-172-31-18-188 SRV-admin]# ssh -iv root@xx.xx.xxx.xx
root@xx.xx.xxx.xx's password:
Connection closed by xx.xx.xxx.xx
```

for check image error in aws console 
         http://goo.gl/PiQQLa

please guide me how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Few things you can cross check.
1. Check your instance not terminated and its pointing to the correct security group.
2. Check if your instance using the same key that you are using to connect it.
3. Check the key file present in the corresponding path you given with right permission to it.

If all ok and still not working still then try to reboot the instance, it might help.

In the worst case, you can take image of the current instance and lunch another instance out of it and terminate the current one.

Comment: thanks to sagest me can your guide me how to done last step.

Comment: 1. Select your instance.
2. At top you see a 'Action' button right to 'Connect' button, Click on that, you will see a option for 'Image'.
3. Create a Image.
4. You can find your created Image in the AMI tab(ON Left menu you will see a link for AMIs under 'IMAGES').
(Please note, it would take few minutes to creat your requested image)
5. Then in the AMI section you can select that image you just created.
6. Then click on 'Lunch'.
Let me know if you face any issue.

But before creating a new instance, try to reboot your current instance, that could solve your connection problem.

Answer (score -1):

Try the solution here. It worked for me. When you try to connect using Java SSH client in AWS console you need to specify the full path for the private key including the file name. As it says path and also specifies the key name at the top it is easy to misunderstand this and just specify the path without the file name. If the full path including the file name is not specified it results in this i/o error.
http://opencartinaws.blogspot.com.au/2016/07/how-to-fix-java-ssh-client-midterm-io.html

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged, and are subject to deletion, as links can change or be removed. Please use the edit link below your post to include the pertintent information for the solution here; you can still include the link for context, but an answer needs to stand on its own.